# How to dynamically set the SequenceGenerator allocationSize?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have to use different values for the allocationSize on one sequence, depending on where it is called (either from a batch or from the normal process).

I currently do that by changing the source code, rebuilding and launching the process, which is far from perfect and can lead to issues.

I have tried using 2 entities for the same table with just a different @SequenceGenerator but JPA/Hibernate doesn't quite like it:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Multiple references to database sequence [my_sequence] were encountered attempting to set conflicting values for 'increment size'.  Found [100] and [1]
```

I have tried rewriting the annotation at runtime but it seems to be cached even before the first entity is created : the rewrite works well (the allocationSize has the required value before making the first call to the repository) but Hibernate keeps using the value that was set at JVM startup.

I think it could work by creating and using a custom SequenceStyleGenerator (or getting the one from the entity) but I have no clue how to do that.

I'm running out of ideas on how to solve that so any advice would be welcome.

Thanks,
Loceka.

PS: we're using JPA 2.1.4 with Hibernate 5.3.7 in Spring Boot 2.1.2

Comment: The big question is...why? Just use a large enough value so it suits both.

Comment: Because the table may contain a large amount of data, so incrementing the sequence by 100/1000 every time we insert only 1 entry is going to become quite problematic (the normal process only creates the entries one at a time, contrary to the batch process). The thing is the batch process performs 3 times faster (2h instead of 6h) with the allocationSize set to 1000, which is a necessity too.

Comment: That's not how it works. It doesn't increment the sequence **every** time you insert, unless you have `allocationSize = 1` which would be a bad idea.